# Use of Simple Tense for future action

Tags: questions

Person 1: Could help me with that file. I am unable to find it in my Inbox?

Person 2: Ok Sir don't worry I send you that file again.

Is above answer suggest future course of action or question must contain shall / Will?

Ans: Ok Sir don't worry I shall sent you that file again.

Answer (score 1):

Ok Sir. Don't worry. I will send you that file again.

Usage of "will" would be more appropriate.

Shall is generally used in very formal situations which I think is not the case here.

We are using Simple Future tense here which indicates that the action - (you sending an email in this case) will happen in future.

We use the first form of verb in simple present tense. So, we will use "send" here and not "sent".

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I guess the **'ll** part can be somewhat inaudible, but simple future tense fits this context much better.
Present simple tense can be used for SCHEDULED future events, which generally appears in "The train departs at 2 o'clock" format.